# what to do Net::HTTPProxyAuthenticationRequired in rspec ruby?

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, proxy

I have request to an address and I have applied a system wide proxy in Ubuntu.
but it seems for requests in my program I have to somehow give the username and password of the proxy again.
Is there  a way to configure this in ruby or anywhere in Ubuntu?